# How can I process @KafkaListener method in different threads?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have kafka handler in spring boot:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic-one", groupId = "response")
    public void listen(String response) {
        myService.processResponse(response);
    }
```

For example producer send one message every second. But `myService.processResponse` work 10 seconds. I need handle each message and start `myService.processResponse` in new thread. I can create my executor and delegate each response to it. But I think there are another configs in kafka for them. I found 2:

1) add `concurrency = "5"` to `@KafkaListener` annotation - It seems to be working. But I'm not sure how correct, because I have second way:

2) I can create `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and set to it `ConsumerFactory` and `concurrency`

I do not understand the difference between these methods? is it enough just to add `concurrency = "5"` to `@KafkaListener` annotation or I need create `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`?

Or I do not understand anything at all and is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an executor makes things complicated, with regard to managing committed offsets; it is not recommended.

With `@KafkaListener`, the framework creates a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` for you.

`concurrency` on the annotation is just a convenience; it overrides the factory setting.

This allows you to use the same factory with multiple listeners, each with different concurrency.

You can set the container concurrency (default) using a boot property; that value is overridden by the annotation value; see the javadocs...

```
/**
 * Override the container factory's {@code concurrency} setting for this listener. May
 * be a property placeholder or SpEL expression that evaluates to a {@link Number}, in
 * which case {@link Number#intValue()} is used to obtain the value.
 * <p>SpEL {@code #{...}} and property place holders {@code ${...}} are supported.
 * @return the concurrency.
 * @since 2.2
 */
String concurrency() default "";
```

Comment: still not fully understand. Ie if I annotated the method with `@KafkaListener` - each handle in this method will in new Thread? because spring create default `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory ` and I do not need create `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory `?

Comment: For concurrency = 5, you need at least 5 partitions on the topic; the partitions will be distributed across the threads - a partition can only be processed by one thread. You don't need to create a factory because boot does it for you with auto-configuration.

Comment: Using an executor makes things complicated, with regard to managing committed offsets; it is not recommended.

Comment: if it's easier, please tell me what should I do to get this logic - 1) I handle message in `@KafkaListener` method. 2) start processing this message in new thread. 3) handle new message....and etc

Comment: You could lose messages that way; it would take me too long to describe the pitfalls and the code you would need to write to make sure the offsets are managed properly, deal with duplicates, etc, etc. I suggest you use the Kafka `Consumer` directly rather than using a listener container.

Comment: it seems I began to understand a little. you suggest not to use annotation `@KafkaListener`. Instead this I need create somthing like "consumers pool"? If it is true can you share some example or article about this?

Comment: Sorry; I don't have time to teach you about how Kafka works; I can only help with using Spring Kafka. Even if you write the code yourself to poll the `Consumer`, you will still have the same problems with regards to managing offsets if you hand off work to asynchronous threads.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I just want to understand how to make it in `spring kafka`. I had a sheduler. It polled a third-party service and when it received the answer it gave it to a new thread for processing. Now I move sheduler to microservice and it send answer to kafka. And my core microservice has become a consumer. I add `@KafkaListener` and process responses. But earlier I did it in several threads and now in one. I just want to understand how I can process the queue faster. So I thought it was possible in `spring kafka`. Make it like I have 5 same cunsumers in one application

Comment: Once again; you can increase the concurrency ONLY if you have at least that number of partitions on the topic; Kafka does not allow multiple consumers on a partition for the same group. If you hand off to another thread, it will add a great deal of complexity with regards to managing the offsets committed for the partition(s). You need to learn more about Kafka.

Answer (score 6):

`concurrency` option has nothing to do with concurrently processing the messages received by the same consumer. It's for consumer groups when you have multiple consumers that each processes their own partitions.

Passing the processing to a separate thread is very complicated and Spring-Kafka team decided not to do that "by design", I believe. You don't even need to dig into Spring-Kafka to understand why. Check the [KafkaConsumer's](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#position-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-) ***Detecting Consumer Failures*** doc:

> Some care must be taken to ensure that committed offsets do not get
>   ahead of the actual position. Typically, you must disable automatic
>   commits and manually commit processed offsets for records only after
>   the thread has finished handling them (depending on the delivery
>   semantics you need). Note also that you will need to pause the
>   partition so that no new records are received from poll until after
>   thread has finished handling those previously returned.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda old question I found here, but I don't think I see an actual answer about processing messages on different threads.

If you don't mind committing your messages with no regard to processing, you can take advantage of `@Async` on your processing logic (and make sure your project has `@EnableAsync` on your application).

Read the messages in your listener:

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "my_topic")
  void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    messageHandlingService.processMessage(record.value());
  }
```

And then in a separate service, annotate your async processing message:

```
 @Async
  public void processMessage(String messageString) {
    // do stuff here
  }
```

Now you can read multiple messages without being blocked by processing them. With all things, there are challenges and caveats and possible configurations, but this might help get you started.